# how to show event title in fullCalendar with laravel

Tags: jquery, events, laravel, fullcalendar, title

I'm trying to use fullCalendar plugin for my customers platform but I got a big problem with the title of events... the calendar doesnt show it!

[Here you can see the error page image](http://cl.ly/image/0p2m3T1h3q17)

HERE MY JS CODE

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: {
            title: 'My Event Title',
            url: '/crud/bussiness/customers/json/{{$id}}',
            color: 'yellow',
            textColor: 'black'
                },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function() {
                 $("#add_booking_modal").trigger("click");
                }
            });
        });
```

HERE MY CONTROLLER CODE WITH THE JSON ACTION

```
    if( $acc == 'json' ){
        return \CompanyBussiness::getCustomers($id);
    }
//CompanyBussiness is the model where Im declarating the getCustomers method for show the events
```

I need fix it because I have to present this platform the next week.

Somebody help me please.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give

```
title: 'My Event Title',
```

-with the `events`.

Instead if you have multiple events, then load `title` along with the JSON encoded array. Make sure that you are loading the 'title' from the JSON action.

If you have Chrome or Firefox, you can simply track it.
Please check by

> **Inspect element** [F12] > '**Network**' > Select **XHR** option

Check if you have a title is passing as event title. Once if you make sure it is, then you will get the result.

Thank you.